# Lambda function can't connect to Lex bot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-lex

I want to invoke my Lex bot from my lambda function, by passing an input (utterance) to my bot.

Here is my Python code:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # Create a new Amazon Lex runtime client
    client = boto3.client('lex-runtime')

    # Send the user's input to the bot
    response = client.post_text(
        botName='BotName',
        botAlias='BotAlias',
        userId='UserID',
        inputText=event['input']
    )

    # Return the bot's response to the caller
    return {
        'output': response['message']
    }
```

I get the following error:

"errorMessage": "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://runtime.lex.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/bot/BotName/alias/BotAlias/user/UserID/text"",
"errorType": "EndpointConnectionError",

My lambda function has the following permissions:
AmazonLexFullAccess
AmazonLexRunBotsOnly

My Lex bot has the basic [Amazon Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Lex) permissions.

Comment: what version of boto3 are you using? try `'lexv2-runtime'` instead of `lex-runtime`

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: @NirAlfasi Thank you so much, yeah I needed to use the 'lexv2-runtime' and adjust the attribute names according to the lexv2 documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I was using 'lex-runtime' instead of 'lexv2-runtime'. The parameters also have to change.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Create a new Amazon Lex runtime client
    client = boto3.client('lexv2-runtime')
    
    # Send the user's input to the bot
    response = client.recognize_text(
        botId='<botId>',
        botAliasId='<botAliasId>',
        localeId='<localeId>',
        sessionId='<sessionId>',
        text='event['input']
    )
    
    # Return the bot's response to the caller
    return {
        'output': response['messages']
    }
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1):

check botName, botAlias, or region in the boto3 client initialization or possible IAM permissions. It is clear that it is EndpointConnectionError. So check and see if there is any missing string values in your URL as well.